# Cast Object Base Class in Object Derived Class

Tags: c#, .net

I'm running the following code:

```
public class CfgObject
{
    protected object _inst;
    public CfgObject(object inst) { _inst = inst; }
}
public class CfgService : CfgObject
{
    public object GetObject() { return _inst; }
    public CfgService(object inst) : base(inst) {}
}
...
CfgObject obj1 = new CfgObject((object)1);
CfgService service = (CfgService)obj1;
service.GetObject();
...
```

I always receive

> System.InvalidCastException (Unable to cast object of type 'CfgObject' to type 'CfgService')

What is the correct way of doing?

Comment: Why would you expect this to work? `obj1` is *not* a `CfgService`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot cast from `CfgObject` to `CfgService`, only from `CfgService` to `CfgObject`.
Casting is always done from derived to base class.

Comment: This isn't true (that casting is always done from derived to base class). Try doing `object o = 5; int i = (int)o;`, for example. Look up "upcasting" vs "downcasting"

Comment: Of course, but you missed one thing: object o = (object) 5; int i = (int) o; o is already an int, so this casting does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want an instance of `CfgService` you need to create an instance of `CfgService`. If you create a supertype (base) you cannot cast it to a subtype. You could do the following, although it would be rather pointless because you might as well just declare `obj1` as a `CfgService`.

```
CfgObject obj1 = new CfgService((object)1);
CfgService service = (CfgService)obj1;
service.GetObject();
```